# getting error while installing after cloning from github

Tags: react-native

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\santo/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\santo\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\santo\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-11T09_37_18_449Z-debug-0.log

after cloning the project from github, while trying to run  npm install on terminal, got the error

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your running the right version on your terminal. Then try again